# Is there any way to show the Features in the Scrum Taskboard

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

The Taskboard only shows PBIs, Bugs and Tasks.

It's difficult to see how the Features are progressing.

Is there any way to show Features in the Taskboard?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not add Features to the scrum board. You can create a custom tree query to show your work hierarchy. The example

[image]

Documentation: [Use a tree query to view hierarchies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#use-a-tree-query-to-view-hierarchies)